# jquery .css(...) not working on safari ( MAC )

Tags: jquery, macos, safari

I have a few links like this:

```
<a href="link" onClick="updateFilter()">
```

In my .js file i have this function :

```
function updateFilter(){
    $(".per_opacity").css({    
        "opacity": "0.3",
        "-khtml-opacity": "0.3",
        "-webkit-opacity": "0.3"
    });

    $(".spinn").css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "display": "block",
        "top": (mouseY - 50),
        "left": "90px"
    });
}
```

This function serves to show a loading/spinner gif when clicking a link. It works on all browsers except on Safari. I have tried a few suggestions and fixes found online, but non seem to work.

Suggestions?

Comment: The page may be being unloaded before the javascript runs if the link is making a standard HTTP request.

Comment: oh, the problem is that link start reloading page before applying my css :) resolved :)